# Using ScopedModel to filter a Flutter ListView throws strange error

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an app where I show a list of strings where the user can type into a `TextField` to filter the list items. I'm using `ScopedModel` to update the filters that I'll apply to the list based on what the user has typed in the parent widget.

My `ScopedModel` works completely fine and I receive an update for each new letter typed.

The issue I'm having is that when I update the list, I get successful filtering when I enter just one or two characters. If I enter three or more, I get an error that I'm not sure I can decipher correctly. I've tried this with lists of 20 items and lists of 2000 items and the result is the same in each case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final List<Content> items;

  MyListView(this.id, this.items);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyListViewState(id, items);
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  final String id;
  List<Content> items;

  _MyListViewState(this.id, this.items);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<ContentListDisplayOptions>(
      builder: (context, child, model) {
        List<Content> filtered = filter(model, items);
        if(filtered == null || filtered.isEmpty) {
          return Column(children: <Widget>[Text("empty")]);
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(filtered[index].name),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  List<Content> filter(
      ContentListDisplayOptions model, List<Content> names) {
    if (noSearchFilters(model)) {
      return names;
    }

    return names
        .where((i) => i.name.startsWith(model.filter.searchQuery))
        .toList();
  }

  bool noSearchFilters(ContentListDisplayOptions model) =>
      model == null || model.filter == null || model.filter.searchQuery == null;
}
```

**ContentListDisplayOptions**

```
class ContentListDisplayOptions extends Model {

  Filter _filter;

  Filter get filter => _filter;

  void updateFilters(Filter filter) {
    this._filter = filter;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Filter {

  final String searchQuery;

  Filter(this.searchQuery);

}
```

The error manifests itself in a strange way too. It doesn't always take up the full screen:

[image: Error output]

Here's the stack trace:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following RangeError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(375.0, 812.0),
flutter: devicePixelRatio: 3.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
flutter: alwaysUse24HourFormat: false)):
flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      List.[] (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:141:60)
flutter: #1      _MyListViewState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:my_app/names/names_list.dart:33:39)
flutter: #2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:197:20)
flutter: #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:716:67)
flutter: #4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcollection_patch.dart:143:29)
flutter: #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:716:26)
flutter: #6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:702:69)
flutter: #7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:671:7)
flutter: #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #11     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3909:5)
flutter: #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #15     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4379:32)
flutter: #16     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4769:17)
flutter: #17     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:192:11)
flutter: #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3909:5)
flutter: #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #29     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #33     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3799:5)
flutter: #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4661:14)
flutter: #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #39     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3799:5)
flutter: #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #43     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3909:5)
flutter: #44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #45     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #46     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #47     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3702:5)
flutter: #48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2699:15)
flutter: #49     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:16)
flutter: #50     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3495:5)
flutter: #51     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2242:33)
flutter: #52     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:626:20)
flutter: #53     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
flutter: #54     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
flutter: #55     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
flutter: #56     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
flutter: #57     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:120:13)
flutter: #58     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:109:3)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3497 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a very small thing. `ListView.builder` takes a value `itemCount` that tells the length of list and you havent mentioned the value of `itemCount` for the `ListView.builder` so the compiler keeps on compiling the itemBuilder function again and again until it gives the error out of range. i.e if your list (filtered) is of length 2 then the error comes when the function runs with index value 2 i.e the 3rd element of list `filtered[2]`
that does not exist coz the filtered list is of length 2 
what you need to do is this:- 
add this property to your `ListView.builder`

```
itemCount : filtered.length,
```